# How do you convert the following from statements to quantified statements given the following predicates.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

*Here are the predicates:*

SameColour(x,y) = (x has the same colour as y).

Cube(x) = (x is a cube).

Circle(x) = (x is a circle).

**a) Some cube has the same colour as some circle.**

$\exists$x Circle(x) $\land$ $\exists$y Circle(y) $\land$ SameColour(x,y)

**b) Every circle has the same colour as every cube.**

$\forall$x Circle(x) $\rightarrow$ $\forall$y Cube (y) $\land$ SameColour(x,y)

**c) Every cube has the same colour as some circle.**

$\forall$x Cube(x) $\rightarrow$ $\exists$y Circle(y) $\land$ SameColour(x,y)

**d) None of the objects have the same colour.**

$\lnot$($\exists$ Cube(X) $\land$ Circle (y) $\land$ SameColour(x,y))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A.  $\exists$x,y (Circle(x) $\land$ Circle(y) $\land$ SameColour(x,y))

B.  $\forall$x,y (Circle(x) $\land$ Cube (y) $\rightarrow$ SameColour(x,y))

C.  $\forall$x (Cube(x) $\rightarrow$ $\exists$y Circle(y) $\land$ SameColour(x,y))

D.  $\lnot$$\exists$x,y (Cube(x) $\land$ Circle (y) $\land$ SameColour(x,y))